# Nextjs seperate process for frontend and backend

Tags: node.js, next.js, nodemon

I am using custom server in nextjs. Everytime I make a change in the frontend or backend, nodemon restarts the main process and the child processes. This results in an increased build time.

My expectation is that when I make a change in the pages or other frontend component, the already running server and the database connection should not restart.

How can this be achieved?

I think if I run the custom server seperatly and use rewrites in next.config then I can have the two server running seperatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GetStaticProps, GetStaticPaths, GetServerSideProps, and GetInitialProps all execute serverside. Actually, unless the component returns JSX it executes on the server. So you have client side and serverside in each pages file, and all serverside in _app and _document. Nextjs has fast refresh so nodemon isn't necessary with Next. Try removing nodemon and just run with `yarn next dev` or `npm run next dev`, [fast refresh](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-4#fast-refresh) is built in

Comment: This exactly what I was looking for. Removed the nodemon and now the changes in the frontend are updating almost instantly.